# Routing DNS (Route 53) to an Elastic Beanstalk application without a loadbalancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Can I route a dns I registered to an Elastic Beanstalk application ***without*** a load balancer?
If so - How? all of the examples show how to do this with a LB..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Can I route a dns I registered to an Elastic Beanstalk application
>   without a load balancer?

Yes, you can use [Single instance type](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-types.html).

> If so - How? all of the examples show how to do this with a LB..

By adding a CNAME which pointed to your EB URL in Route 53.

Comment: But there is NO easy way to setup `SSL` without load balancer.